# What browser or any tool can reduce flash CPU usage?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, cpu, flash-player

OS: windows XP SP3

While listening to Pandora in Chrome, the CPU usage is almost to 100% for a single core in CPU. Is there any way to reduce CPU usage? Either by using another browser, any plugins that reduce flash CPU usage, or like in Linux, there's a lightweight client - Pithos for Pandora. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the latest version of Flash? I find Pandora to be fairly resource light when idling. What happens when you run Flash in other browsers, do you have this problem? I have found that Chrome and Flash don't always go hand-in-hand.

Comment: I have Adobe flash player 10. I tried on IE, the CPU usage is below 10% or even less. But Chrome is just always remains 50% (I got a Core Duo).

Comment: So you can use IE. Or maybe try [one of these](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/01/31/7-ways-to-listen-to-pandora-without-a-web-browser/).

Answer (score 1):

Since flash is a closed-source, compiled binary, I don't think you'll find any plugins, addons, or programs which can modify the way it does things (i.e., reduce CPU usage).

Your best bet will be to try a different browser, or try re-installing google chrome (or try a different version, as I believe there's "stable", "beta", and "development" versions).  Google partnered up with Adobe recently to distribute flash with chrome, so I'd expect these two to play much nicer in the future when they start shipping new builds with flash built in.